# Set paper-button text dynamically in polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Trying to add the submit button dynamically through javascript, below is the code snippet, not sure which attribute to use for setting the text.

```
      var dynSubmit = document.createElement("paper-button");
      dynSubmit.setAttribute("on-click", "submitForm");
      //dynSubmit.setAttribute("Value", "Submit"); 
      parent.$.iron-form.appendChild(dynSubmit);
```

The commented code does not work, How do i set the caption of submit button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the button's `innerHTML`.

```
Polymer.dom(dynSubmit).innerHTML = "Submit";
```

Thanks to @jonsS0 for his handy comment.

Comment: You should use `Polymer.dom(dynSubmit).innerHTML`. Otherwise you might ruin the button's ripple effect.

Comment: @jonS90 your single comment has helped me save hours of effort (after spending hours already) :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `innerHTML` with Polymer, or at all really; it's slow, it's where XSS can get in, and you shouldn't need it.

Instead use `textContent`:

```
dynSubmit.textContent = 'Submit';
```

You can set this without breaking the ripple and you shouldn't need the `Polymer.dom(dynSubmit)` as it's an exposed property on the underlying element.